# Why does CSS background-origin behave differently based on the width?

Tags: css

I'm curious why background-origin behaves differently based on the width of the element it's applied to.

I have two divs, all CSS is identical except for the width:

```
col-sm-1 width: calc(100% * 1 / 12);
col-sm-6 width: calc(100% * 6 / 12);
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/xm73pa6u/5/

When I apply a background-image with background-origin: content-box the padding on the right and bottom is "obeyed" on the larger div, but not the smaller div.

I'm aware I can use background-clip in conjunction with background-origin on the smaller div to visually get similar behavior, shown with col-sm-2.

I'm curious why the default behavior is different.

Comment: both behave the same for me. Padding-right is covered and not padding-left

Comment: Which browser are you using? I just checked this across Chrome, Firefox, Opera, and Safari. Chrome, Firefox, and Opera show the padding right as not covered for col-sm-6. Safari does cover the padding right at both sm-1 and sm-6.